# wkhtmltopdf, 0.12.6, Warning: Blocked access to file

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

When upgrade `wkhtmltopdf` to `0.12.6`, it came to such messages and the image did not show in the target pdf:

```
    Warning: Blocked access to file /path/to/bpa_product_layering.png
```

BTW, the same source html file works well with `0.12.5`

Answer (score 154, accepted):

This is caused by the change of default behavior in version 0.12.6 of `wkhtmltopdf`. `wkhtmltopdf` disables local file access by default now. It could be solved by adding the command line parameter

```
--enable-local-file-access
```

or the combination

```
--disable-local-file-access --allow <path>
```

Comment: please add an example..how can i add command line parameter? i am using phthon

Comment: @sanjay, I ran into the same issue with Python, you can pass in options in the form of a dictionary. In this case, you could use the option `"disable-local-file-access":""`.

Comment: when you get this, when using pandoc then use `pandoc --pdf-engine-opt=--enable-local-file-access`

Comment: i have same problem in symfphony any idea how to finx it ? snapy pdf library

Comment: Just using `--allow` works for me on version 0.12.6.

Comment: This is almost right, but insufficient/incorrect - c.f. @Shrimp's answer below for the extra correction needed.

Comment: Can we allow multiple paths ? or with a regex ? or with something like `*/my/very/last/folder` ?

Answer (score 42):

For those that are using **laravel-snappy**, add the 'enable-local-file-access' option in the config\snappy.php:

```
'pdf' => [
        'enabled' => true,
        'binary'  => env('WKHTML_PDF_BINARY', '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf'),
        'timeout' => false,
        'options' => [
            'enable-local-file-access' => true,
            'orientation'   => 'landscape',
            'encoding'      => 'UTF-8'
        ],
        'env'     => [],
    ],

    'image' => [
        'enabled' => true,
        'binary'  => env('WKHTML_IMG_BINARY', '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage'),
        'timeout' => false,
        'options' => [
            'enable-local-file-access' => true,
            'orientation'   => 'landscape',
            'encoding'      => 'UTF-8'
        ],
        'env'     => [],
    ],
```

wkhtmltopdf disables local file access by default in the 0.12.6 version

Answer (score 28):

Just bumping this thread with a correction in case you're still getting the same error in spite of using:

```
--enable-local-file-access
```

For some reason, this cmd line argument does not work when being specified after input/output files, you have to write this argument right after *wkhtmltopdf.exe*.

So

```
wkhtmltopdf.exe --enable-local-file-access input.html output.pdf
```

instead of other variants.

Comment: Yes, the sequence matters. In 0.12.4, it was fine...

Answer (score 4):

in my case, I put `"enable-local-file-access": "",` in options, it worked.

Answer (score 4):

In Windows with Python, I came across a similar error as well when running code:

```
result = imgkit.from_file('postlayout.A.html', 'out.jpg', config=wkhtmltoimage_binaries)
```

**Error:**

> Warning: Blocked access to file C:/XXXXXX/background.A.jpg
>
> Error: Failed to load about:blank, with network status code 301 and
> http status code 0 - Protocol "about" is unknown

**What I did to resolve this:**

*Add variable options*

```
kitoptions = {
  "enable-local-file-access": None
}
```

**Add options to call**

*FROM*

```
result = imgkit.from_file('postlayout.A.html', 'out.jpg', config=wkhtmltoimage_binaries)
```

*TO*

```
result = imgkit.from_file('postlayout.A.html', 'out.jpg', config=wkhtmltoimage_binaries, options=kitoptions)
```

**Full Source:**

```
import imgkit

#library path to kit
path_wkthmltopdf = r'C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltoimage.exe'
wkhtmltoimage_binaries  = imgkit.config(wkhtmltoimage=path_wkthmltopdf)

#OPTIONS
kitoptions = {
  "enable-local-file-access": None
}

html_file_directory = r'C:\XXXX\template'

result = imgkit.from_file('postlayout.A.html', 'out.jpg', config=wkhtmltoimage_binaries, options=kitoptions)
if result:
    print("successful")
else:
    print("failed")
```

Answer (score 2):

For the C API, contrary to what the documentation says, it's not `load.blockLocalFileAccess` but `loadPage.blockLocalFileAccess` that you must set to `"false"`:

```c
wkhtmltoimage_set_global_setting(settings, "loadPage.blockLocalFileAccess", "false");
```

Hopefully, the documentation will be updated soon; see [issue #4763](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/4763).

Answer (score 1):

I confirm that the problem comes from the wkhtmltopdf version. For those on Symfony (3.4), just add an option in config.yml:

```
knp_snappy:
    pdf:
        options:
            enable-local-file-access: true
```

Answer (score 0):

I know am a bit late in party but just wanted to write clear example with c# here so one can understand clearly.

```
ProcessStartInfo proc = new ProcessStartInfo();
        proc = new ProcessStartInfo();
        proc.RedirectStandardError = true;
        proc.UseShellExecute = false;
        proc.WorkingDirectory = @"" + Config.WkhtmltopdfPath;
        proc.FileName = @"" + Config.WkhtmltopdfPath + @"\wkhtmltopdf.exe";
        proc.Arguments = @"  --enable-local-file-access -T 0 -B 0 --page-width 210mm --page-height 450mm " + fileName + ".html " + fileName + ".pdf";
        Process inkscape = Process.Start(proc);
```