# pdfkit- Warning: Blocked access to file

Tags: python, pdfkit

I am getting an error(Blocked access to the file) in HTML to pdf conversion using pdfkit library while using a local image in my HTML file.
How can I use local images in my HTML file?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I faced the same problem. I solved it by adding "enable-local-file-access" option to pdfkit.from_file().

```
options = {
  "enable-local-file-access": None
}

pdfkit.from_file(html_file_name, pdf_file_name, options=options)
```

Comment: Using wkhtmltopdf 0.12.6 and pdfkit 0.6.1, this option for me, while kimbespo's did not.

Answer (score 4):

[Pdfkit](https://pypi.org/project/pdfkit/) is a python wrapper for [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/). It seems to have inherited the default behaviour of wkhtmltopdf in recent versions, which now [blocks local file access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62315246/wkhtmltopdf-0-12-6-warning-blocked-access-to-file) unless otherwise specified.

However, since pdfkit allows you to specify [any of the original wkhtmltopdf options](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt), you should be able to resolve this problem by passing the `enable-local-file-access` option.

Following the example on the pdfkit site, that would probably look something like this:

```py
options = {
    "enable-local-file-access": ""
}

pdfkit.from_string(html, output_path=False, options=options)
```