# Can't convert HTML to PDF using pdfkit (empty file)

Tags: python, html, pdfkit, file-conversion

I want to convert a HTML file to PDF

#### Example Input

The [HTML file from Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KYR_lvl6YySKAvgzzg8JPhCc9G5S-_dL/view?usp=sharing) looks good, can see content in my browser.

#### Code

```
import pdfkit # convert html to pdf

pdfkit.from_file('income_contract_01.html', 'res.pdf')
```

#### Issue

I expect to see data in `res.pdf`.  But instead I see an empty file:

- no text
- but the same number of lines

Environment and versions used:

```
python 3.9
pdfkit versiion 1.0.0
wkhtmltopdf is the newest version (0.12.2.4-1)
OS Ubuntu 16.04
```

How can I fix the error? Don't see any error messages.

**Update**: I was trying to specify library in configuration but it didn't help

```
import pdfkit # convert html to pdf v1

path = "/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf"
config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=path)
pdfkit.from_file('income_contract_01.html', 'res123.pdf', configuration=config)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with using `wkhtmltopdf`.

Once you download it from [here](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html) then put `wkhtmltopdf.exe`'s path to variable in code below which is `path_wkhtmltopdf`.

```
import pdfkit

path_wkhtmltopdf = r"C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe"
config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=path_wkhtmltopdf)
pdfkit.from_url("income_contract.html", "res.pdf", configuration=config)
```

Result: [res.pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oCo_e0CpbTAIU9nn-HVWq1V5xx_GetJX/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thank you, but this didn't help me (result is the same - empty file)

Comment: What is the result of your code with my file (link above)?

Comment: I added result link to answer.

Comment: Downvoted, because OP didn't ask for Windows solution, rather has Linux/Ubuntu mentioned as OS. Please hold your answer generic and add OS-specific configurations as separate section to you answer.

Comment: Anyway, he/she tried to adding path. I just wanted to point out that he may use path. Another point of view :/

Comment: pdfkit is a wrapper for wkhtmltopdf. Can you try this `wkhtmltopdf --enable-local-file-access income_contract_01.html res123.pdf`

Comment: This should solve your issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62814607/pdfkit-warning-blocked-access-to-file