# Static images are not rendering in production on pdf using wkhtmltopd in django application

Tags: django, docker, web-applications, wkhtmltopdf, production

I am using pdfkit to convert html into pdf. Everything seems to be working perfectly in development, but after building a docker image and running it locally, the pdf is generated but images are not loaded.

Here is my how I am rendering image, which seems to be working fine locally:

```
<img src="{{ host_url }}/static/tcs.jpg" style="width:100px;display:block;" />
```

Here's my code in django view function:

```
template = get_template("tcs_invoice.html")
data = {
  "host_url": settings.HOST
}
html = template.render(data)  # Renders the template with the context data.
pdf = pdfkit.from_string(html, False)
 return HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
```

I have installed wkhtmltopdf on my docker container. When I hit the url in the browser the image is shown. why does it not render in production mode.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue this answer did the trick: [wkhtmltopdf, 0.12.6, Warning: Blocked access to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62315246/wkhtmltopdf-0-12-6-warning-blocked-access-to-file?answertab=votes#tab-top)

It ended up being a change of behavior after wkhtmltopdf 0.12.6 where local file access is disabled by default, so you need to wether specify the files you want to allow using the `--allow <file>` option or set `--enable-local-file-access` to allow any files.

Answer (score 0):

So after trying almost everything, even aws s3(privet bucket) none of them work !
The only way to pass the image with URL ; but we can't always do that in the case of confidential(in my case ) static images like signatures. solution?

```
If you are hosting it I mean env is Linux add this to settings.py:


STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT=(
os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
)
STATICFILES_DIRS =[
     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles'),
 ]
```

1.Then your static files will be here ,0.0.0.0/static/img/....

2.You need to pass the image in html page through url only to be converted to PDF

3.From the backend get the domain and pass the url to page

```
from django.contrib.sites.shortcuts import get_current_site
current_domain = get_current_site(request).domain


template=get_template('template location like template/some.html')
                template_render=template.render({'value':yourquery,"current_domain":current_domain})
                
                options={
                'page-size': 'Letter',
                "enable-local-file-access": None,
                "disable-smart-shrinking": None, 
                "zoom": "0.7",}
                pdf=pdfkit.from_string(template_render,False,options)
                response = HttpResponse(pdf,content_type='application/pdf')
                response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; 
                filename="ourcodeworld.pdf" '
                return HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
```

4.In this way you will be able to pass the domain cause it might change.
5.

```
change the static  :
<img src="{% static 'img/someimage.png' %}> 
  to 
<img src="http://{{current_domain}}/static/img/someimage.png">
```

It works everywhere! even in EC2.
Upvotes are appreciated, Thank you!