# Laravel snappy returning Failed to load about:blank, with network status code 301 and http status code 0 - Protocol "about" is unknown Error

Tags: laravel, wkhtmltopdf, laravel-snappy

I am using laravel snappy based on wkhtmltopdf, everything was ok, but now on server and local I am getting this error:

> Failed to load about:blank, with network status code 301 and http status code 0 - Protocol "about" is unknown Error.
> And
>
> Blocked access to file /var/www/app/public/css/app.css

And no image is rendered in pdf.

This is so strange and discouraging to always being debugging snappy.
I do not understand the issue and do not know how to fix it.
anyone can help me please?
thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @kellymandem , please try this 
                ->setOption('enable-local-file-access', true) .  If it works, let me know I will answer my question with this. thanks

Comment: @Cutis Thank you so much, you saved me :)))))))

Comment: @kellymandem setOption('enable-local-file-access', true) worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

With Laravel Snappy, you need to use this option

> enable-local-file-access

like this :

```
->setOption('enable-local-file-access', true)
```

I also discover this link after : [wkhtmltopdf, 0.12.6, Warning: Blocked access to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62315246/wkhtmltopdf-0-12-6-warning-blocked-access-to-file). It will help too.